# How to sum tensors with same labels?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have two tensors: labels with shape (n, m) and source with shape (n, m, embdim), and I need to get for each label its embedding as a sum of embeddings from source with same corresponding label.

`out[i] = source[labels == i].sum(0)`

For example:

```
labels = [[0, 1], [1, 2]], 
source = [[[0, 1], 
           [1, 2]], 

           [[2, 3],
            [3, 4]]]
out = [[0, 1], [3, 5], [3, 4]]
```

Is there a way to do it fast, without looping over label values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeap, i think i found a solution via [index_add](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.index_add_.html) function, which also keeps gradient flow:

```py
def sum_by_index(labels, source):
    unique_labels, labels_inds, labels_counts = labels.unique(return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    out = torch.zeros((unique_labels.size(0), source.size(2)), dtype=source.dtype)
    out.index_add_(0, labels_inds.flatten(), source.flatten(0, 1))
    return out

labels = torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
source = torch.tensor(
          [[[0, 1], 
           [1, 2]], 

           [[2, 3],
            [3, 4]]], 
        dtype=torch.float, 
        requires_grad=True,
)
print(sum_by_index(labels, source))
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[0., 1.],
        [3., 5.],
        [3., 4.]], grad_fn=<IndexAddBackward0>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `np.add.at()` to add to an array using a second array to choose the index:

```
import numpy as np
labels = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
source = np.array([[[0, 1], 
           [1, 2]], 
           [[2, 3],
            [3, 4]]])
embdim = source.shape[-1]
max_label = np.max(labels) + 1
out = np.zeros((max_label, embdim))
np.add.at(out, labels, source)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [3. 5.]
 [3. 4.]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! But i need pure pytorch solution, which doesn't break gradient flow to embeddings in `source`